# Interpretting arima xreg output in R

Tags: r, arima

I have an interrupted time series consisting of 200 observations that I've cleaved into two subseries: a sub-series of 150 pre-interrupted observations, and a sub-series of 50 post-interrupted observations. So the overall structure looks like this:

series = pre-interrupted + post-interrupted

I've fitted the pre-interrupted series with an ARIMA(1, 0, 0) model, and everything looks good. When I run the model in R I get good residual plots and something like this:

```
> arima(pre-interrupted, 1, 0, 0)

## Coefficients:
##           ar1   xmean
##         0.792  51.472
## s.e.    0.082   2.418
```

I created an indicator variable, which to my understanding functions like a dummy variable. It looks like this:

```
indvar <- c(rep(1, 150), rep(0, 50))
```

And then I run the arima command with that included:

```
> arima(series, c(1, 0, 0), xreg = indicator)
```

And get something like this:

```
## Coefficients:
##           ar1   intercept      indvar
##         0.761      59.721      -8.178
## s.e.    0.082       2.996       1.842
```

And I'm not exactly sure how to interpret this. Specifically:

Why did the xmean change to intercept?

What is the role of indvar in the context of the output?

Comment: Do you have a variable name with a simple hyphen like `pre-interrupted`, or did you just make it up as an example? I don't think you may have variable names like that in `R`. I guess it is just an example as the other arguments `1, 0, 0` also look unorthodox.

Comment: You need to change indvar <- c(rep(0, 150), rep(1, 50)) and rerun arima, it is much easier to interpret coefficients this way. What this would tell you is that there has been an incremental 8.178 unit lift in the level post interrupted series.

Comment: @Richard Hardy I just made that up. I thought it would be easier to communicate the overall idea without putting the entire scenario up there. Sorry if it added confusion.